# On complex exponential sum estimation

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables

Let $c>0$ a real number, let $N$ a large natural number and let $e\left(x\right):=e^{2\pi ix}$. Is it true that $\forall k\in\left[1,\,2N\right]$, $k$ natural number, that $$\left|\underset{\underset{n_{1}+n_{2}=k}{2\leq n_{1},\, n_{2}\leq N}}{\sum}\left(\log n_{1}\log n_{2}\, e\left(c\left(n_{1}+n_{2}\right)\right)\right)\right|\leq\left|\underset{2\leq n_{1},\, n_{2}\leq N}{\sum}\left(\log n_{1}\log n_{2}\,e\left(c\left(n_{1}+n_{2}\right)\right)\right)\right|?$$

Comment: Where do the parentheses go around the "log(n_1)" and "log(n_2)" terms?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's certainly not true as written. The right side is just
$$
\left | \left( \sum_{2\le n\le N}  e(cn)\log n \right)^2 \right|
= \left|\sum_{2\le n\le N} e(cn)\log n \right|^2.
$$

If you choose $c$ to be 1/2, this is just the square of an alternating series (and hence is
bounded by $(\log N)^2$.

On the other hand, if you choose $k=N$ on the left (say $N$ is even), you've got approximately $N(\log N)^2$.

This can be done with irrational $c$ as well if you take a bit of care.

Comment: It is not forbidden to take $c=1$.

Comment: If c=1, then the inequality holds. It's if there's cancellation that it fails.